# Excel - Using Slicers and Subtotal Numbers In Table Column while Ignoring Duplicate Values Identified with another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, slicers

I have a workbook with Five columns.  First Name, Last Name, Age, Household Count and Address.

I have slicers setup in the workbook which I can filter on the Age and Household Count.

I also have a SUBTOTAL to show me a count of how many rows I have with data when I apply the slicer.

But I want to have another SUBTOTAL that gets me the household total ignoring duplicates.

Example:

```
First Name|Last Name|Age|Household|Address
John      |Jay      |33 |2        |1234 ABC Street
Maria     |Jay      |33 |2        |1234 ABC Street
Albert    |Wood     |40 |3        |1111 ABC Street
Frank     |Wood     |14 |3        |1111 ABC Street
Jessica   |Wood     |33 |3        |1111 ABC Street
```

I want to sum the household column but ignore duplicates from the Address column.  So in the above example with no slicer clicked the total would be 5. Because there are only 2 unique address and one address with household of 2 and another with household of 3.  If I clicked the slicer for age 33 it should give me 3 names John Jay, Maria Jay and Jessica Wood and the subtotal on the household should be 5 as well cause the same two address showed up and one had a household of 2 the other of 3. Finally If I remove the slicer to only show me age 14 then only Frank Wood would appear and only 1 address so the Subtotal would be 3 as he is in a household of 3.

**This is the query which I have now which can count the unique address but I want it to sum the household numbers based on unique address not sure what I have to do to change that.**

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(E24,ROW(E24:E40000)-ROW(E24),0)),IF(E24:E40000<>"",MATCH(E24:E40000,E24:F40000,0))),ROW(E24:E40000)-ROW(E24)+1),1))
```

Comment: That's exactly what pivot tables are for.

Comment: I have everything in a table which uses slicers to view the data.  So its dynamically updating.